# Move a git repository to another repository as a subfolder while keeping history

Tags: git, github

I have created and worked on a git repository `github.com/softtimur/old`. I just created another git repository `github.com/softtimur/Documents`, which has its own `.../Documents/.git/`. Now I want to create `.../Documents/old` and move everything of `github.com/softtimur/old` under it while keeping the commit history. And then, I want to remove `github.com/softtimur/old`.

Does anyone know how to do this moving properly?

Answer (score 1):

I would add another remote to your local checkout of `github.com/softtimur/old` to allow you to to merge them and then push the result back

```
git clone git@github.com/softtimur/old.git
cd old
git remote add new git@github.com/softtimur/Documents.git
git fetch new
git checkout master
git merge new/master
git push -u new master
```

Comment: In which local folder should I start doing this?

Comment: What folder you are in before the git clone doesn't matter, however, I assumed that there was a folder in git@github.com/softtimur/old.git called old, if there isn't you probably should make one, move all files to that folder and commit before your do the merge to simplify it

Comment: `git checkout master` returns `Already on 'master' Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.` `git merge new/master` returns `Auto-merging README.md CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in README.md Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.`